# libncurses.so.5()(64bit) is needed by MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64

Tags: mysql, fedora

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6.33 on Fedora 24 64-bit using an RPM (the latest MySQL 5.7 is not an option for me).
Installation of the server went smoothly with:

```
$ rpm -i MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
```

Then I wanted to install the client, but got a dependency error:

```
$ rpm -i MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
warning: MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libncurses.so.5()(64bit) is needed by MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
```

Every search result said that I need to install ncurses, and so I did, but the problem persists.

```
$ dnf install ncurses-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 2:12:25 ago on Thu Sep 29 17:05:20 2016.
Package ncurses-devel-6.0-6.20160709.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
$ rpm -i MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm
warning: MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 5072e1f5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        libncurses.so.5()(64bit) is needed by MySQL-client-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64
```

Comment: where did you get that RPM from? Why don't you just `dnf install mysql`?

Comment: @Jakuje I got it from the dev.mysql.com. I don't use dnf because I need 5.6 specifically and dnf provides me with 5.7.

Comment: And what is the problem with the version 5.7? When you do `dnf install MySQL-server-5.6.33-1.linux_glibc2.5.x86_64.rpm` from the directory where you have the RPM downloaded? If not, you will have to rebuild that, hopefully from MariaDB in Fedora.

Answer (score 2):

Run `yum provides */libncurses.so.5` will show the available yum repositories for libncurses.

The output will be something like below

> ncurses-compat-libs-6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3.i686 : Ncurses
> compatibility libraries Repo        : amzn2-core Matched from:
> Filename    : /usr/lib/libncurses.so.5
>
> ncurses-compat-libs-6.0-8.20170212.amzn2.1.3.x86_64 : Ncurses
> compatibility libraries Repo        : amzn2-core Matched from:
> Filename    : /usr/lib64/libncurses.so.5

Based on the bit version of the OS you can choose the package and install it as follows.

```
yum -y install ncurses-compat-libs-6.1-7.20180224.el8.x86_64
```